# Texts below desktop's Icons became blue in Windows XP! How can I fix it?

Tags: windows, desktop, icons

I don't know how, but the text below my desktop icons became blue the last few days.

[image: My Desktop]

How can I restore them to the Windows XP default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This website gives a quick way to make the label's background transparent again:
http://www.entity.cc/icon-label-transparent.php

Comment: Consider improving your answer by explaining the process here too, and not only providing an external link.

Comment: Sorry about that, that was my first answer and I hadn't seen any other questions yet. No point changing it now... but I'll remember that for next time.

Comment: no problem, it was only a suggestion, for a better answer. Welcome to this site! Think that questions on this site are not only for the one person who asked, they will easily reach first pages of search results in Google (and others), so it's not only about this answer right now, it is also about other people who will find it later. In such case, there is a point in editing this answer to improve it with more information, as it can be found later too. Think that the links you refer can die, this is why I recommended you to add more information about the process, in your answer .

Comment: (while still referring to the original source, of course, the point is not to steal information, only to make sure it is visible for a long time, and useful to others as well).