# get rid of blue background behind the desktop icons

Tags: windows, windows-xp, icons

Today morning there was some problem with my pc and i forced Restart.
After that i can see some Blue background behinde every icon.

I have seen [Texts below desktop's Icons became blue in Windows XP! How can I fix it?](https://superuser.com/questions/122103/texts-below-desktops-icons-became-blue-in-windows-xp-how-can-i-fix-it),but didn't help me.

So, How to get rid of blue background below the desktop icons ?

Comment: You also have to make sure to enable the *drop-shadow* option in the *Performance Settings* dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2-3 methods to accomplish the task but the once which actually worked for me is

Desktop>> Right click> Properties> Desktop> Customize Desktop> Web> then you will see couple of web pages just **uncheck both**… and press OK…
Its done.

Comment: You certainly live up to your handle.

Answer (score -3):

Under normal circumstances, you can't change the blue background on Windows XP because it's hard coded into the operating system, I said "Under normal circumstances" because I did see and tried out a utility a few years ago that would allow you to change it, however, it would only stay the color you change it to while the utility was running.  I don't remember what the name of the utility was or if it's still available.  I seem to remember that it might have been making Windows XP unstable so I un-installed it.